# Android App How to override autocorrect on Samsung devices on EditText fields

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm building an Android app that has some `EditText` (text entry) fields. One in particular is an address field. This is the current `inputType` specification I have set in the layout XML:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textPostalAddress"
```

It works great on Google Nexus devices that are straight up Android. No autocorrect happens on these devices unless autocorrect is specified.

When running on a Samsung Galaxy S5, it appears that Samsung is overriding this with their bloated OS (sorry, I cannot stand forceful bloating). The example I can give, if you enter **91st** it tries to autocorrect it.

I don't believe there should be any autocorrection enabled for an address entry field.

Am I stuck, or is there a way for me to override Samsung and their devious ways? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `textNoSuggestions` like so,

`android:inputType="textCapWords|textPostalAddress|textNoSuggestions"`